# Play MP3 audio data on iPhone

Tags: iphone, mp3, audio-streaming

I need to play mp3 audio data in iPhone continuously. I am getting continuous mp3 data via server in iPhone. Now I need to play this data in iPhone. I cannot access url to play as it is of mms protocol. So, for playing this type of data which is the best method to use. Can anyone help me out with this thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: one thing you can do is store that data in NSdata when it comes from server , me playing the mp3 song as alarm in my app, first i save that song in document directory and then play it

Comment: You should follow up on your questions and select some answers. People will come to ignore your questions over time if you don't.

Comment: Hello App   i also do the same but i also need to make our iphone as http server and store the audio in the same and do the audio streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options sanctioned by or directly from Apple. You should look into:

- [Core Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577) and the [Audio Toolbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CAAudioTooboxRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002089)
- The [AVFoundation Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008072)
- The [OpenAL Framework](http://www.openal.org/)

Also, you can try [Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer class](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/streaming-mp3aac-audio-again.html). It should be able to do the job, or at least help you figure out how to do so, if you look at the code.

Between those four options, there should be something to help.

**NOTE:**

After writing this, I did a bit of Googling and I found [this thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=520845) that discusses the possibility of streaming MMS media to iPhone. It appears that it is *not possible*, due to the cost of a license from Microsoft. In theory, the above-mentioned frameworks should do everything you need, but it seems that you cannot because of the licensing issue.

Good luck!

Comment: No. It won't help. I have already used this application. It is just play song using specific URL not from data. I need to play only data.

Answer (score 0):

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:<#(NSData *)data#> error:<#(NSError **)outError#>];

try this else tell me more clear what you want to do

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. But I need to play mp3 data using content of File. I am continuously storing mp3 data in output.mp3 file. And playing mp3 file using:    audioRadio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:uniquePath] error:nil]; But I am not able to play continuously as it is giving blank in every block.

Comment: can you give me link from where data is comeing and i will test in my code , in my code i have list of mp3 songs and video songs , when i click on any one then spinner come and load it after load it start playing song

Comment: This is the link from where I am getting data. mms://216.185.43.237/radiocity 1. We cannot get data directly using mms protocol. It need to be converted using some library. So, By that I am getting data in mp3 format using ffmpeg and libmms library.

Comment: sorry then i helpless becoz me not done this before me just pick song from a webservice and play in iphone , you need path of video if you want to play it else you can't play that song